# Converting Scala case class to PySpark schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics, pyspark, py4j

Given a simple Scala case class like this:

```
package com.foo.storage.schema   
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

it's possible to create a Spark schema from a case class as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import com.foo.storage.schema.Person  

val schema = Encoders.product[Person].schema
```

I wonder if it's possible to access the schema from a case class in Python/PySpark. I would hope to do something like this [Python]:

```
jvm = sc._jvm
py4j_class = jvm.com.foo.storage.schema.Person 
jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.product(py4j_class)
```

This throws an error `com.foo.storage.schema.Person._get_object_id does not exist in the JVM`. The `Encoders.product` is a generic in Scala, and I'm not entirely sure how to specify the type using Py4J. Is there a way to use the case class to create a PySpark schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found there's no clean / easy way to do this using generics, also not as a pure Scala function. What I ended up doing is making a companion object for the case class that can fetch the schema.

**Solution**

```
package com.foo.storage.schema
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
object Person {
  def getSchema = Encoders.product[Person].schema
}
```

This function can be called from Py4J, but will return a `JavaObject`. It can be converted with a helper function like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
import json
def java_schema_to_python(j_schema):
  json_schema = json.loads(ddl.json())
  return StructType.fromJson(json_schema)
```

Finally, we can extract our schema:

```
j_schema = jvm.com.foo.storage.Person.getSchema()
java_schema_to_python(j_schema)
```

**Alternative solution**

I found there is one more way to do this, but I like the first one better. You can make a generic function that infers the type of the argument in Scala, and uses that to infer the type:

```
object SchemaConverter {
  def getSchemaFromType[T <: Product: TypeTag](obj: T): StructType = {
     Encoders.product[T].schema
  }
}
```

Which can be called like this:

```
val schema = SchemaConverter.getSchemaFromType(Person("Joe", 42))
```

I didn't like this method since it requires you to create a dummy instance of the case class. Haven't tested it, but I think the function above could be called using Py4J too.